# How can I use "testing.Benchmark" in a Benchmark function

Tags: go, testing, benchmarking

my testing file

```golang
func BenchmarkA(b *testing.B) {
    res := testing.Benchmark(BenchB)
    if res.N <= 25{
        b.Fatalf("fail!")
    }
```

```
func BenchB(b *testing.B) {
for i := 0; i <= b.N; i++{
        url := "****"
        contentType := "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        data := strings.NewReader("****")
        _, err := http.Post(url, contentType, data)
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal("fail ")
        }
    }
}
```

when i run

```
go test -bench=./router_test.go
```

I get a

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

if i use "package main" and "func main{}", the program can run successfully.

what should i do next? (forgive my poor english)

Comment: Why do you want to use `Benchmark` in a Benchmark function? From [document](https://pkg.go.dev/testing?tab=doc#Benchmark), it seems that it should not be used with go test command.

Comment: The argument to `-bench` is **not** a filename (the `go` tool mostly doesn't work on files!) but a regexp to match benchmark function name!

Comment: I  use "testing.Benchmark" in my Benchmark function because I want to fetch the result of "BenchB". Do you have another way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a method that is not particularly good

```
func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    res := testing.Benchmark(BenchB)
    if res.N <= 25{
        t.Fatalf("fail!")
    }
```

benchmark -> unit test

Comment: If you want a test that does pass/fail against a benchmark's performance, `N` is not the metric to judge by; use [`NsPerOp`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#BenchmarkResult.NsPerOp) instead.